# Node.js client side - how to store safely variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, client

Lets say I have a boolean variable VIP:

```
var VIP = false;
```

Then futher in code I have a function which checks if user is VIP. If so, give him special benefits:

```
function setBenefits(){
    if(VIP)
        //set VIP benefits
 }
```

But then I realized that user can change the VIP variable in browser via console.
Now the question is - how to safely store the variable which client cant touch it on the client side.

Thank you, have a nice day!

Comment: Store it on server side

Comment: @ponury-kostek Oh, how do I get it from serverside? Via ajax? Thanks! ^_^

Comment: There is many ways to get variable from server side, ajax is one possibility